# mysql on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, database

I am using mysql option to update result on duplicate. It works fine to update result. Now I was trying to concatenate existing row result with previous one and I used + and . concatenation operators but it is giving error.

Here is the pseudo code

```
insert in table 1
on duplicate key update prod_name = "abc" concatenate with existing result
```

so if there is record XYZ in the row then it should be XYZ, abc and on next 
duplicate it should be XYZ, abc, dpg and so on

Comment: This smells of a normalization problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the mysql function `concat()` ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)).

The SQL would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (prod_name) VALUES ('abc')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prod_name=concat(prod_name,',','abc')
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$sql= " INSERT INTO table (prod_name) VALUES ($x)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prod_name='prod_name+$x' ";
```

**Note:** `prod_name` should be *UNIQUE index* or *PRIMARY KEY*

#### edit

try this

```
  $sql= " INSERT INTO table (prod_name) VALUES ($x) ";
  $sql .= is_numeric($x) 
   ? " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prod_name=prod_name+$x "
   : " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prod_name=CONCAT_WS(',',prod_name, $x) ";
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, it doesn't work. For product name it can also contain digits only. When there are only digits, it sum them up and it also does not put comma between two names

Comment: put the condition on `$x` and make two different query

Comment: I am sorry, but could you please provide example what do you mean by condition on $x